# Using old Dojo 0.9 in new Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, dojo, web-parts

I have a Web-Application using old Dojo Framework 0.9.
Migrating to a new Dojo would be very time-consuming.

In a simple iFrame my web-application is running.
But when I start it in a Sharepoint2013 Webpart, dojo doesn't seem to "initialize" properly.

In main.aspx I use some div-Containers as Node for Main-Window, Pop-Up etc.
When the the login-popup should be displayed, the node is not found in PopupContainer.js using Manager.js

Is there a cross-domain-problem or do I have to configure Sharepoint2013...

Thanks in Advance.

## Code Snippets:

### main.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/dojo.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
...  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.ContentPane");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.SplitContainer")  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.LayoutContainer");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.HtmlWidget");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.Dialog");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.Menu2");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.Tooltip");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.Button");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.FloatingPane");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.CWComboBox");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.ComboBox");  
        dojo.require("dojo.widget.PopupContainer");  
        ...  
        dojo.hostenv.writeIncludes();  
...  

<body id="content">  

        <% Process(); %>    
        <div dojoType="ContentPane" visible=false isLoaded=true  dojoAttachPoint='containerNode' widgetId="MenuPane" label="Empty" style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden;" executeScripts=true cacheContent=false>
        </div>  
        <!-- Dummy Pane for popup containers -->  
        <div dojoType="ContentPane" visible=false isLoaded=true dojoAttachPoint='containerNode' widgetId="PopupContainerPane" label="Empty" style="width:300px; height:300px; overflow:hidden;" executeScripts=true cacheContent=false>
        </div>  
        <!-- Dummy Pane for Dynamic Dialogs -->  
        <div dojoType="ContentPane" visible=false isLoaded=true dojoAttachPoint='containerNode' widgetId="DialogPane" label="Empty" style="width:0px; height:0px; overflow:hidden;" executeScripts=true cacheContent=false>
        </div>  
        <!-- MainPane -->  
        <div dojoType="CWContentPane" isLoaded=true id="w_1" widgetId="w_1" label="Empty" style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;" executeScripts=true cacheContent=false adjustPaths=false parseContent=true scriptSeparation=false>
        </div>  
    </body>
```

...

### Dialog.js

...
*cDialogPane remains undefined, because widget _strDialogPane is not found in Manager.js*

```
var cDialogPane = dojo.widget.manager.getWidgetById(_strDialogPane);
    if (null == cDialogPane) {
        alert('dojo.dialog.loadDialog: null == DialogPane');
        window.location.replace(dojo.session.getErrorPage());
    }
```

### Manager.js

*id is undefined, because widgetIds-Array is empty, but at least should be filled with the divs defined in main.aspx*

```
... 
    this.getWidgetById = function(id){  
            if(dojo.lang.isString(id)){  
                return this.widgetIds[id];  
            }  
            return id;  
        }  
...
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, it would be useful knowing the error or provide more details about the initialization. How did you notice it was not initializing properly? (do you have any screenshots?) Have you tried defining `_strDialogPane`? According to `Manager.js` it should be a string and only one id. How do you expect `main.aspx` to provide this id in order to get something in `cDialogPane` var?

Comment: The error is of course "dojo.dialog.loadDialog: null == DialogPane');",

Comment: ...as you can see in my provided "Dialog.js".

Comment: I noticed the failing initialasation, because  without a SHarepoint frame the widgetIds-Array is filled with the dojoType-Names given in the main.aspx.

Comment: This issue is not relevant any more.

Comment: Would you care to detail Daniel? If you found the solution to your problem, you can answer your own question, which may help other people in the future (more than these comments). I'm not familiar with sharepoint/dojo and I still don't fully understand the problem, but if you think other people may have it, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we do not have a solution for that, but we are using a modern version of Dojo now.
Possibly it was a sort of CORS issue we had with Dojo 0.9.
This Version was created, when IE8 was state of the art and nowadays the web security has developed, but Dojo 0.9 not. :-)